# How to search through array of strings using BETWEEN in Active Record POSTGRES,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
Subscriptions
    canceled_at: ["2017-04-07T09:52:17-05:00", "2017-04-01T09:52:17-05:00"]
```

Canceled_at is an array of strings. Each element is a DateTime converted to a string.

Above is my subscriptions table. I am trying to query through and find records that have a canceled_at date within a given week.

```
date = Date.today

Subscription.where("ANY subscriptions.canceled_at 
    BETWEEN '#{date.beginning_of_week(:sunday)}' 
    AND '#{date.end_of_week(:sunday)}'"
```

ruby 2.3.1p112

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Subscription.where(canceled_at:(date.beginning_of_week(:sunday)..date.end_of_week(:sunday)))
```

Edit: missing closing parentheses

Comment: This receives an error, as canceled_at is an array of Dates.

Comment: Isn't canceled_at a column in your subscriptions table?. The code was missing a last parentheses.

Comment: Yes it is a column on the sub table. It however is an array. The above returns an error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "2017-04-09"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

Comment: Oh. Some times is hard to tell. Is it serialized, array saved as string? I would not recommend to do that way, can you cancel a subscription more than once witouth an indications that it has been reactivated?  But if you show more detail of the data structure it is still possible to get the data but it will perform very poorly if you have many records.

Comment: The subscription can be canceled and reactivated many times. The reactivation date is not too important to me. I mainly just want to keep track and see if during a given week this subscription was canceled. The canceled_at: column is an array of date times represented as strings. Would you still be able to pull if a given date was in range?

Comment: Yes but you the work that could have been done easier in the database now will require to read all records, parse the arrays and return the subscription entries that you need.  You can see a way to select dates from an array, -coincidentally today- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286891/splitting-up-an-array-of-dates-for-writing-a-conditional/43287042?noredirect=1#comment73642524_43287042  . This won't scale  if you have a lot of records. You should add a related table ex. subscription_events and query that one.